# Multiple keys pointing/refering to same Object in values in HashMap

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I have a HashMap , which has a Object (with 2 String objects as member variables of it) and value as Object containing 3 different Strings.

Say:

```
Map<ReqDTO , RespDTO> map = new HashMap<ReqDTO ,RespDTO> ();
```

suppose I have following values :

```
    KEY             VALUE
1 ("str1","1") -  ("1","2","3")
2 ("str2","2") -  ("a","b","c")
3 ("str3","3") -  ("1","2","3")
4 ("str4","4") -  ("v","b","g")
5 ("str5","5") -  ("1","2","3")
```

When I have thousands of such records , (which is Cache in my application) , then VALUE part of record number : 1,3,5 is holding memory of 3 objects. I want to make KEYS of 1,3,5 records to point to same instance of the VALUES (1,2,3 , in this case) and not as separate memory.

Is there any variant in HashMap for the same? or Any other Datastructure will do..

*NOTE*: It is loaded only once and all the operations performed on this are READ only..
What should be the preference of datastructure to make it performance intensive ,In other words, It can have costly insertion.

Comment: Please be specific and don't provide pseudocode. What specifically are your keys and values? (The key on the first line might be `-1`, or it might be an object whose fields are `"str1"` and `"1"`, or something else entirely. The value might be an object with fields, or an array, or something else.)

Comment: The key is Object whose fields are 2 Strings... -1 ,-2... are the ordering which I tried to give, to which I am referring in the scenario. As I am new to stackoverflow , So I was kind of struggling to put the line in new row. Sorry for that.

Comment: What are the values, and why are you wanting to do this? There are techniques to make it work, but they have their own costs, and thousands of records isn't much on today's computers.

Comment: These are the sample values, so that everyone can understand. Actual DTO has 11 fields , with variable values , so there are around 2 lac objects as of now and expected to grow more. This is just one part of the cache which is loaded from database at the start up of an application and is occupying lot of memory because value part is unique object always.

Comment: Please don't use "sample values", since it makes it a different question. What persistence system are you using? Can you not trust it to handle the duplication issue?

Comment: Not enough knowledge on that Chrylis. I am loading the data in the Maps provided by Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a technique called interning, which is essentially mapping all objects that are `equal()` to each other to a single authorative instance.

That's used in Java for Strings using `String.intern()`.

**But** there are some drawbacks to using this method ('though they have been reduced quite a lot with modern JVMs). As an alternative you can use the [Guava](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) interface [`Interner`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interner.html).

Just create a single `Interner` using the [`Interners`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interners.html) helper class:

Interner strInterner = Interners.newStrongInterner();

and pass each `String` value through the interner before using it in a key *or* value:

```
String v1 = strInterner.intern(param1);
```

This way for any given value, you'll only ever use 1 `String` instance. The same can be done for any other class (as long as it correctly implements `equals()` and is immutable).

You can even discard the `Interner` after you've constructed the map.

Comment: OP, don't miss "immutable". That's Important.

Comment: Thanks for interesting info :) , but the scenario here is related to complex objects. Is interning possible for other objects as well? , because String has its private pool , but other classes don't have.

Comment: @Sarthak: well, I *did* tell you about `Interner` and how you can use it on any other immutable object that implements `equals()` as well. You *could* use it on mutable objects as well, if you ensure that the interned instance is never changed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you put the same object into the map for both keys, then they'll both be the same object. If you have different instances of the object that are `.equals()` to each other, it gets more interesting. You could try using `Flyweight` for your value objects, or you could walk through the `values()` of the map - if you find an `equals()` value object, put your key with that object instead of the one passed in.

Someone, somewhere has probably already written a `Map` implementation that does what you want, but my best recommendation there is to use Google and hope they're good at SEO.